# Pandas & seaborn: how to classify survey answers based on predefined criteria

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, cluster-analysis, survey

I have a survey. with 119 question, each question imported in a df as a column.
each answer for the survey is a row in the df.

Most variables are categorical variables, some of them allow multiple answers.

What I want to do is trying to approach this as the following.

| Company ID | Bank Account? | Accounting Practice | Accountant? | External Auditor | Online Banking? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | Accounting system | Yes | No | No |
| 2 | No | Book keeping | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| 3 | Yes | Accounting system | Yes | Yes | Yes |

I want to classify each company (row) as Organized, Semi Organized and Not organized.

based on their answers to a subset of questions.

For example, if a company has a bank account, Accounting practice, Accountant, Registered trade name and Tax number

this company will be labeled as organized.

I have other criteria for semi organized and other for not organized

Is this obtainable and how?

Noting that the end result is trying to cluster it all based on employees segment.
Since most variables are categorical, it seems I can't cluster them because they are not numerical
I am a still a beginner in this.
please help